# Android - 'cursor.close()' may produce 'java.lang.nullpointerexception'?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have bellow code which works just fine, but produces a warning:

```
method invocation 'cursor.close()' may produce 'java.lang.nullpointerexception'
```

[image: code with warning]

Comment: Who get me **negative rating** ,I don't know this problem .

Comment: This is only a warning, so you can probably ignore it. Also, above that, you have  `catch (nullPointerException)`, Which is a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586290/is-catching-a-null-pointer-exception-a-code-smell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor_id` may not be initialized, as, e.g., your `try` block checks. You need to add the same validation in the `finally` block:

```
} finally { 
    if (cursor_id != null) {
        cursor_id.close();
    }
}
```